# Esp8266 How to parse HTTP Response

Tags: esp8266

I send http get request to web server with my ESP8266. And my server
returns;

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Sat, 22 Jul 2017 11:16:10 GMT Server:
>   Apache/2.4.10 (Raspbian) Content-Length: 16 Connection: close
>   Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
>
> Important Part

As you can understand i need "Important Part" to for assign a variable. I don't want to use external library. I think if we say whole message is equal x, and HTTP response part is y, if we do x - y we find the "Important Part" right?

How can we do it, how can i read until charset=UTF-8 to get payload ?

Comment: Why not use an external library? There are many portable C-libraries which work out of the box, e.g. https://github.com/nodejs/http-parser (example: https://gist.github.com/ry/155877)

Comment: Look at the HTTP protocol, there should be two carriage return line feeds between the headers and body.  Read and discard until you find that.

Comment: What firmware/SDK do you use (Arduino, NodeMCU, etc.)?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for 2 CRLFs in row (HTTP [spec](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html)). Start reading from the beginning of your receive buffer, once you encounter 0xD 0xA 0xD 0xA, you are at your Important Part.